# Criar Controller em uma pasta especifica em Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Estou com uma pequena dúvida que me veio, estou aprendendo Laravel, e até agora para criar um `controller` usei o comando `php artisan make:controller`, ele deixa o `controller` na pasta `Controller` na estrutura de arquivos, mas quero criar um controller em outra pasta para organizar os arquivos, e simplesmente recortar não funciona, ou o comando `php artisan make:controller pasta/control --resource` também não vai, alguém me ajuda com esta dúvida?

Answer (score 2):

Envolve entre aspas duplas pasta e `controller` que funciona:

```
$ php artisan make:controller "Utils\SpaceController" --resource
```

onde `Utils` é uma pasta criada e o `SpaceController` o próprio `controller`.

[Documentação - Controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/controllers)

*Se você mudar o seu `controller` de forma manual, também deve atualizar esse `namespace` e por isso que não funciona.*

Answer (score 1):

Basca definir o diretório aonde quer criar o controller, por exemplo:

```
php artisan make:controller test/testController
```

O controller será criado dentro do diretório `test/`

Caso ja tenha criado e queria move-lo, será necessário redefinir o `namespace` para que se adeque ao diretório aonde ele está.

Por exemplo, caso tenha criado na raiz de **Controllers** o namespace será assim: **`namespace App\Http\Controllers;`** bastaria mover para a pasta test e adicionar ao `namespace` o novo caminho, por exemplo: **`namespace App\Http\Controllers\test;`**

Referencias: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/structure

Comment: Obrigado Bulfaitelo, me ajudou basntante!

Comment: @MichelDiniz se a resposta ajudou a solucionar seu problema, marque como solucionado o problema